# Transform CustomObject Inputstream to bitmap on Quickblox

Tags: java, android, bitmap, inputstream, quickblox

I am trying to download an image from quickblox backend but I don't know ho to transform the recieved inputstream to a bitmap.
Here my code:

```
QBCustomObjectsFiles.downloadFile(co, "fieldName", new QBEntityCallback<InputStream>(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InputStream result, Bundle params) 
        {
            Bitmap bm= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(result);

            if (bm!=null) 
            {
                job.foto = bm;
            }
            else
            {
                App.getInstance().log("ERROR");
            }
        }
```

The output error is DECORDER-->DECODER ERROR

Comment: What do you mean with output error? Please tell how your code flows. Is onSuccess() triggered?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @greenapps . Yes, the onSuccess() is reached correcctly. What I mean with the output error is that the app crashes whith this los error:

Comment: D/skia: ---- read threw an exception

D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false

The result.tostream() is: com.quickblox.core.request.ProgressHttpEntityWrapper$ProgressFilterInputStream@c913d95

Comment: Dont decode the stream with bitmap factory but save all bytes to file. After that examine at ease.

Comment: What do you mean? How?

Comment: I dont understand your error. BitmapFactory.decodeStream() will return a valid bitmap or null. Now what does it return?

Comment: `What do you mean? How?` ?? Those are two questions. And they do not match.